# Generating PL/SQL script to create copy of records from many related tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

For a given table and the unique ID of one record in that table, what's the easiest/quickest to generate a PL/SQL (or SQL) script that creates a copy of that record, then creates copies of all records from tables with a foreign key relationship to that record, and then all tables with a foreign key relationship to those 2nd tier records, and so on until all related records in all directly or indirectly related tables in the schema have been copied?

Such a script would be useful in capturing and reproducing the state of a record and all descendant records for testing purposes.

Considerations:

- Schema has 500+ tables so writing this script manually would be slow.
- Avoid unique constraint violations by ensuring that the new records have their own generated/altered primary key values. Generate new IDs using max(id_column) + 1 rather than sequence, to simplify problem.
- Use Oracle metadata tables to gather list of tables, and maybe primary key and foreign key columns (?).

Thanks.

Comment: There is a tool that claims to be able to do that: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jailer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the FKs are present and valid, you would drive this from dba_constraints, starting with r_constraint_name = the PK constraint of the start table. For each table found, you would query dba_tab_columns and build your queries and generated inserts from here. You would do this recursively to capture all the tables in the tree. To make it easier, I would generate a stored procedure table_ins wrapper, so that when you generate you INSERT you instead call the store_proc to avoid having to generate the INSERT ( col1, .... ) for each row.